# Vis.js: Lessen layout noise for multiple central nodes (radial force)

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm working with vis.js to display some graphs. The problem is that layouts with multiple central nodes get noisy (the central nodes' neighbours overlap). A layout similar to the attached image is desirable.
Is it possible to achieve this using vis.js?

[image]

Comment: try playing with physics configurator http://visjs.org/examples/network/physics/physicsConfiguration.html

Comment: by the way, if you provide a snippet that reproduces the problem, there's a much higher chance that you get an answer. I can imagine that if you set initial coordinates properly then there's a better chance to get a nice layout; but to check if that can help, I need actual data

Comment: There is an entire app that uses vis.js to display the data, it's not really easy to provide a snippet. Also, there isn't a 'problem', it's a feature or a combination of settings I'd like to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is an option that should solve your issue (I've found it after playing with [physicsConfiguration](http://visjs.org/examples/network/physics/physicsConfiguration.html) like I suggested earlier):

physics has `avoidOverlap` property (float between `0` and `1`) that can be used like this:

```
var options = {
  ...
  physics: {
    barnesHut: {
      avoidOverlap: 0.5
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

If you try it in the configuration demo, you'll see that with `avoidOverlap` equal to `0` it's quite possible to drag and move nodes so that those overlap edges and the network stays in that position:

[image]

but once we increase this value, nodes start to be bounced from edges and can't really stay in that position:

[image]

Note though, that this option doesn't prevent edge-edge crossing, only edge-node overlapping (see [physics](http://visjs.org/docs/network/physics.html#optionTable)/barnesHut/avoidOverlap). The physics docs page doesn't contain the word "cross" at all and each occurance of "overlap" is about edge-node thing.

So this will make the layout less noisy, but won't eliminate crossed edges.

Comment: The physicsConfiguration tool is now available [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/physics/physicsConfiguration.html). Thanks for sharing, Yakov!